# Are TYPO3 Flow Resources allowed with no ending?

Tags: php, frameworks, typo3, typo3-flow

we use the TYPO3 Flow 2.3 integrated Resource object to upload any kind of files in our project. The definition in our `File` object is:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource
 * @ORM\ManyToOne
 */
protected $originalresource;
```

And the fluid call goes like:

```
<a class="filelink" data-icon="{file.filetype}" href="{f:uri.resource(resource: file.originalresource)}" target="_blank">{file.name}</a>
```

Everything in this constellation works fine until a user uploads a file without ending like `hosts`. The server says `Not Found` in the regular Apache error style. Are files without endings supported or not? Why does this happen?

The Setting is:

```
TYPO3:
  Flow:  
    resource:
      storages:
        defaultPersistentResourcesStorage:
          storage: 'TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Storage\WritableFileSystemStorage'
          storageOptions:
            path: '%FLOW_PATH_DATA%Persistent/Resources/'
      targets:
        localWebDirectoryPersistentResourcesTarget:
          target: 'TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Target\FileSystemSymlinkTarget'
          targetOptions:
            path: '%FLOW_PATH_WEB%_Resources/Persistent/'
            baseUri: '_Resources/Persistent/'
```

And the created symbolic link for the `hosts` file in `_Resources/Persistent/` is named with the hash and then a dot without file ending pointing the the actual file. The actual file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug and you can report it here: https://jira.neos.io/

In Flow 3.x it works fine, but there were major changes with resource management.

Adding one line to Web/.htaccess should solve the problem, but I can't tell it's best solution.

```
# Perform rewriting of persistent resource files
RewriteRule ^(_Resources/Persistent/.{40})/.+(\..+) $1$2 [L]

# Add this line - consider security
RewriteRule ^(_Resources/Persistent/.{40})/.+ $1. [L]
```

---

And answer why it happens - persistent resources are stored by default in `Data/Persistent/Resources/<hash>` and in you have symlink there from `Web/_Resources/Persistent/<hash>.extension`. So standard symlink looks like that:

```
0c73666545d393d3d2d6b5a2039dceab56fb3aa2.txt -> /www/FLOW/23/Data/Persistent/Resources/0c73666545d393d3d2d6b5a2039dceab56fb3aa2
```

If file has no extension there is just dot at the end

```
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3. -> /www/FLOW/23/Data/Persistent/Resources/a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

So in fact link returned by ResourceViewHelper (FileSystemPublishingTarget) is correct, but first rewrite rule above requires extension. Adding second one you catch files without extension and just add . at the end to match correct symlink with hash and dot at the end.

Comment: So you recommend to upgrade to Version 3.x?

Comment: It's up to you and depends on your project. I'm using 3.x in my current project but I havent upgraded previous yet. Check [what changed](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/ReleaseNotes/300.html) - play with it and decide. Changes in resource management, security framework and adding support for php7 speaks for 3.x and upgrade shouldn't be difficult.. But for now this one line in .htaccess should solve your problem.